# Exporting Freeform Entries returns a .csv file that does not exist

Tags: solspace-freeform, export

I'm using Freeform Pro (4.2.0) with EE 2.10.1, and Freeform exports have stopped working. The issue might or might not be related to updating EE: I'm not 100% sure (e.g., Freeform exports might have been "broken" a long time ago).

When I attempt to export form entries (964 entries), everything works fine: I get the options to specify how I want the form exported, and then I'm told the export is building and will download when ready.

The download, however, is a 1KB file with the following text:

```
File freeform_contact_form_export_20151125_0621_40.csv does not exist.
```

That file exists on the server in the cache folder: `/system/expressionengine/cache/freeform/freeform_contact_form_export_20151125_0621_40.csv`.

So all the plumbing seems to work; client just can't download the file via the Control Panel. They have to FTP, and, for obvious reasons, I'd rather not make them do that.

What's causing the broken download? You'll note that my cache path is above the webroot. Is that it?

Comment: We are having the same issue here, did you fix this @cherrypj?

Comment: @paulcripps: no. Still an outstanding issue.